# What is the complexity of this code that repeatedly subtracts values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

I have this code and want to know its time complexity:

```
    int N,M; // let N and M be any two numbers 
    while(N != M && N > 0 && M > 0){
       if(N > M)N -= M;
       else M -= N;
    }
```

I don't know how to analyze this, since the values of M and N decrease in unusual ways.  Is there a standard way to approach this?

Comment: If N==1 and M==0 you get an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm sorry i correct it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is a naive implementation of the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).  At each iteration, you're subtracting out the smaller number from the bigger one, so you can divide the algorithm into "phases."  Each phase consists of subtracting as many copies of the smaller number out of the bigger one until the bigger number drops below the smaller number. (This is connected to a procedure the Ancient Greeks knew about call *anythpharesis*) A modern version of this could would just be to mod the bigger number by the smaller number, which is known to terminate within O(log min{M, N}) steps (this is the modern Euclidean algorithm) and spend O(1) time on each step, assuming the numbers are represented as integers.

In this case, we know that there will be O(log min{M, N}) phases, but each phase won't take a constant amount of time.  Using the geometric intuition behind anythpharesis, it's possible to construct pairs of numbers where it will take a very long time for each individual phase to terminate, so the best bound that I'm aware of would be to say that the runtime is O(N + M).

In short: this code is inefficient compared to a modern implementation, which runs in logarithmic time.  It's hard to get a good upper bound on the runtime, but realistically speaking it doesn't matter since you would probably just rewrite the code to be more efficient anyway. :-)

Hope this helps!